# Unable to save objects to a vector c++

Tags: c++

```
            Sprite1 *enemy = new Sprite1(100, 100, "enemy.bmp", *screen);
            enemy->DrawJon(screen);

            enemyList.insert(enemyList.end(), *enemy);
```

For some reason, the enemy is not being stored in the list. Any ideas?

## EDIT:

Also how to access the objects and use them after wards like:

```
for (int g=0; g<enemyList.size(); g++)
            {
                Sprite1 enemyToMove = enemyList.at(g); //.at(g);
                enemyToMove.MoveJon(0, 50, screen);
            }
```

## EDIT:

So even though this got closed I still want people to know what the solution was. I had not made a constructor that set the properties on the class. In the end I was able to get this working with a default constructor and a setter method

Comment: No idea if this actually causes the errors, but for appending, you'd prefer `.push_back`. Also, you don't seem to need that dynamic allocation and pointer -- if you can, just use stack allocation.

Comment: Yes.  You didn't define the variable `enemyList`, so your code clearly doesn't compile.  Compiling code is more likely to work.  (Post http://sscce.org/ -- they work much better)

Comment: Does the enemy object have a copy constructor that does a deep copy of the object if necessary?

Comment: Oh, and `Sprite1 enemyToMove = enemyList.at(g); enemyToMove.MoveJon(0, 50, screen);` copies an enemy out of the list, then does something on the copy, then destroys the copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It inserts a copy of the object before the end of `enemyList`. For this, you should really prefer `enemyList.push_back(*enemy)`. However, note that it is a *copy*. If you want to be referring to the same object inside and outside of the `std::vector`, you're going to want a vector of pointers (preferably smart pointers). For example:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Sprite1>> enemyList;

std::shared_ptr<Sprite1> enemy(new Sprite1(100, 100, "enemy.bmp", *screen));
enemy->DrawJon(screen);

enemyList.push_back(enemy);
```

Alternatively, use a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper>`.

If you *have* changed your `std::vector` to contain pointers or `std::reference_wrapper`s, you can just access the enemies like so:

```
std::shared_ptr<Sprite1> enemyToMove = enemyList[g];
// or
std::shared_ptr<Sprite1>& enemyToMove = enemyList[g];
```

If you're still containing `Sprite1`s directly, you need to keep a reference to the object returned by `operator[]` or `at`, otherwise you'll copy it:

```
Sprite1& enemyToMove = enemyList[g];
```

Comment: So this makes sense and should be working. When I debug, I see that nothing is stored in enemylist. No idea why. Is there something in my class I need to implement in order for vector to work with it?

Comment: @JonathonO You're getting no errors? Have you tried checking the value returned by `enemyList.size()`?

Comment: @JonathanO Then your `insert` or `push_back` is never executing.

Comment: See my last edit but you were right. This does work. Thank you for your help. Its people like you who keep this community alive. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not storing `enemy` in the list, it is storing a **copy** of enemy.

You probably want to change the type of enemyList to be a `std::vector<Sprite1*>` and then you can use

```
enemyList.insert(enemyList.end(), enemy);
```

to insert your object (or replace it with `push_back()` for brevity).

This approach means you have to look after the allocated memory e.g. when you clear your list, but this will get you going for now.

Answer (score 0):

.end() returns the element past the last one stored in the vector. As such, it's an invalid position at which to insert things.

To append an object to the end of a vector, use .push_back()